# on a sewing machine or by a sewing machine

Tags: word-choice

> Mother made our clothes **on** a sewing machine.
>   Mother made our clothes **by** a sewing machine.

Which is better, *by* a sewing machine or *on* a sewing machine?
I found both usages in google.

So I want to know "the way of sewing clothes" can be expressed "by sewing machine".

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation of the _meaning_ you intend to express.

Comment: If you find widespread usage of both, chances are that both are grammatical and perhaps the meaning differs slightly, as @Max mentions.

Comment: When you use 'by' to indicate a method, you don't usually put the indefinite article after it - "by sewing machine". This NGRAM gives some idea how frequently they are used. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+sewing+machine%2Con+a+sewing+machine%2C+using+a+sewing+machine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20sewing%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20sewing%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusing%20a%20sewing%20machine%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

"Mother made our clothes *on* a sewing machine" or "Mother made our clothes *with* a sewing machine".  Both seem to be about equally common.

You can also say, "Mother used a sewing machine to make all our clothes."